# Auto fill form data after autocomplete="off" and value=""

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a simple log in form in php, and I have two forms each on in separated web-page.

when I fill the log in information and go to another form in another web-page, the new form is filled automatically with the same data of the log in form.

And when I go back to log in page after logging out, the credential fields are filled the the old data as well.

I tried value="" for each input and autocomplete="off" and the autocomplete wasn't disabled. and I don't want to cache the data on the forms.

How to prevent one form to use the data from another?
and how to prevent caching the data and autofilling?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to apply the autocomplete="off" on the form tag and not in the input tag?

```
<form action="" method="" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

(or any other random string value for autocomplete, as suggested by Mozilla)?

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion